# InfoPath 2007 in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Can we deploy and use InfoPath 2007 forms in SharePoint 2013? Would there be any compatibility issues in future if we keep them as InfoPath 2007 compatible?

Our forms have code behind and are administrator approved.